# Running multiple Erlang SDK versions side by side

Tags: erlang

Someone once showed my an open source tool for downloading building and managing multiple Erlang SDK's on a single machine but I can't for the life of me remember what it was called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you thinking about [kerl](https://github.com/yrashk/kerl)?

First you'd build a release:

```
kerl build 18.0 my-18.0
```

And then install it:

```
kerl install my-18.0 ~/erl-18.0/
```

To use it, either run the programs in `~/erl-18.0/bin` directly, or source `~/erl-18.0/activate` to add that directory to `PATH`:

```
source ~/erl-18.0/activate
```